# Should I use 'did' or 'were'?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I have these 2 sentences:

- > I wonder what went through their mind when they cried. **Were they remembering** all the good memories?
- > I wonder what went through their mind when they cried. **Did they remember** all the good memories?

Should I be using 'were' or 'did'? which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: They're both grammatically correct.

Comment: okai thank uuu :3

Comment: They are both correct. However, unless you are using *they* as "the singular *they*" — for one person — you need the plural *minds* (multiple people = multiple minds).

Comment: @TinfoilHat ohh i was actually using they as the plural they. so I guess I need to change mind to minds huh? thank u for pointing that

Comment: Well, there is the expression "they have one brain between the both of them," but that's generally not considered a good thing.

Comment: You can also use the singular if the group is making a common decision. "The impeachment managers changed their mind and decided not to call witnesses."